# Will an Amazon EC2 instance automatically refresh its own IP at some time interval?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, autoscaling

A running EC2 instance will automatically change its old public ip to the new public ip at some point of interval.  Is that true??

If so how many days it will take to reflect the new ip in our instance. Can some one pls explain.

Answer (score 2):

Per [Amazon EC2 Instance IP Addressing](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_pv/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-instance-addressing.html):

> A public IP address is assigned to your instance from Amazon's pool of
>   public IPv4 addresses and is not associated with your AWS account.
>   When a public IP address is disassociated from your instance, it is
>   released back into the public IPv4 address pool, and you cannot reuse
>   it.
>
> You cannot manually associate or disassociate a public IP address from
>   your instance. Instead, in certain cases, we release the public IP
>   address from your instance, or assign it a new one:
>
> - We release your instance's public IP address when it is stopped or terminated. Your stopped instance receives a new public IP address
>     when it is restarted.
> - We release your instance's public IP address when you associate an Elastic IP address with it. When you disassociate the Elastic IP
>     address from your instance, it receives a new public IP address.
> - If the public IP address of your instance in a VPC has been released, it will not receive a new one if there is more than one
>     network interface attached to your instance.
> - If your instance's public IP address is released while it has a secondary private IP address that is associated with an Elastic IP
>     address, the instance does not receive a new public IP address.
>
> If you require a persistent public IP address that can be associated
>   to and from instances as you require, use an **Elastic IP address**
>   instead.